# Get just class names from string selector, jQuery way?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have string selector such as:

```
input.js-pretty-select[type="radio"].selected
```

How can I get **just all class names** (`js-pretty-select` and `selected`) from this string, possibly using some jQuery core function?

I thought about some regex at first, but then I realized that jQuery might have that already implemented somewhere in it's code, like when resolving selectors with `$()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to extract the classes from a string using regular expression:

```
// This function accepts a string and return array of classes
function getClasses(s) {
    var matches = s.match(/\.[a-zA-Z][\w-]*/g);
    var classes = [];

    for(var i=0; i < matches.length; i++) {
      classes[i] = matches[i].substr(1);  
    }
    return classes;
}

var c = getClasses('input.js-pretty_3select[type="radio"].selected');
```

Comment: Both, yours and Krishna's answers are enough for my needs, although regular expressions seem to be more solid, and that's why I mark your answer as correct. Thank you all for responses!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$("input.js-pretty-select[type='radio'].selected").attr('class')
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this returns `undefined` when such element does not exist in DOM tree...

Comment: I am sure you can handle existence of an element in Jquery :)

`if($("input.js-pretty-select[type='radio'].selected").length)`

Comment: That is right, but I need these class names regardless of element existence.

Comment: You are confusing an element with a selector. The question is asking how to retrieve the class names from the selector, not the element that is matched.

Answer (score 1):

JSFIDDLE DEMO => http://jsfiddle.net/s1g2mwor/

```
var str = 'input.js-pretty-select[type="radio"].selected';

var arr = str.split('.'); //["input", "js-pretty-select[type="radio"]", "selected"]

arr.splice(0, 1); //removing the first entry (input)

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].split('[')[0]; // removing [type="radio"]
};
console.log(arr); //["js-pretty-select", "selected"]
```

Note: This code will only work for the string you've provided. If you want something more complex your code will need to handle all the complex scenarios